# How to Choose When to Hyphenate, Maybe, Two Nouns

Tags: hyphens

> No vehicular stand still ever made him late, for work.

or,

> No vehicular stand-still ever made him late, for work.

Which may you choose, as proper, and grammatical English grammar?

Comment: Not sure why you would say "vehicular standstill" instead of "traffic jam".

Answer (score 0):

[Standstill](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/standstill) is a standalone word; hyphenation is irrelevant.

> No vehicular **standstill** ever made him late, for work.